# js errors with Uncaught SyntaxError about argument list

Tags: javascript, syntax

when i write js,i meet with some wrong about SyntaxError,the following is `part of my code

```
    function loadData() {
                tree = new dTree('tree');
                tree.add(0, -1, '请选择父类')
     $.ajax({
            url : "${ctxPath}/type/list",
            dataType : 'text',
            type : 'get',
            async : false,
            success : function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                                  
            tree.add(obj[i].id, obj[i].pid, obj[i].name, 
            'javascript:setSrcValue(/''+ obj[i].name + '/',/''+ obj[i].pid+ '/')'
                                                            ); 
                                                }
         var srcElement = null;
    var valueElement = null;
        showTree =function (item,valueId){
        srcElement = window.event.srcElement;
        valueElement = document.getElementById(valueId);
        var x = getLeft(item);
        var y = getTop(item) + item.offsetHeight;
        var w = item.offsetWidth;
        blockDTree(x,y,w);
        }
  setSrcValue=function (text,value){
            srcElement.value = text;
            valueElement.value = value;
            hiddenDTree();
        }
```

But my error is : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.I don't know how to modify it?  what's wrong with my code?   what's the reason?   @Jaromanda X

Comment: You have to make sure you `'` are balanced and make sense. This is just a syntax error.

Comment: can you tell us what exact value you want from `javascript:setSrcValue(/''+ obj[i].name + ' / ',/''+ obj[i].pid+ ' / ')');
`

Answer (score 0):

老铁，格式化下代码，你就可以从格式上看到问题所在了，最好用 ide，可以直接显示错误

Answer (score 0):

try template string with backticks **`**.

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
tree.add(obj[i].id, obj[i].pid, obj[i].name,
    `javascript:setSrcValue('${obj[i].name}' , '${obj[i].pid}')`);
}
```